# Обширный вопрос по backend

Tags: golang, backend

Проясните пожалуйста несколько базовых моментов (ответы на некоторые пункты можно ответить просто набором ключевых слов, я пока что не знаю в каком направлении смотреть вообще):

1. Если я допустим написал какой то простенький веб сервер на Go, то как я понимаю мне его нужно задеплоить где нибудь на хостинге. Для этого мне нужно каким то образом переместить бинарник на этот хост и как то описать конфигурации nginx (пусть будет nginx) чтобы этот nginx осуществлял проксирование на мой сервер. Как этот процесс вообще происходит?
2. Я узнал что nginx отдаёт статические файлы сразу с диска. Как мне разместить эти файлы на этот диск?
3. Как мне в коде задать порт, на каком будет висеть мой сервер? Ведь хост должен сам как то определить порт моего сервиса, и в то же время мне нужно как то его указать, чтобы скомпилировать исходники (или он указывается в качестве параметра...)
4. Как мне разместить базу на хосте? Допустим я решил SQLite использовать и она со временем допустим очень сильно вырастет. Будут ли какие то санкции применятся со стороны хоста, за то что я сожрал своей базой много ресурсов?
5. Какой стек технологий желательно знать, чтобы потянуть бэкэнд на go?

Answer (score 1):

1. В Вашем случае задеплоить - это просто скопировать файл на сервер. Обычно хостеры сами указывают, в каком каталоге можно размещать пользовательские файлы. Если же сервер "личный/железный", то в принципе можно разместить где угодно, но в случае go бинарей, либо  в домашнем каталоге, либо в папке вебсервера для бинарей. Также сейчас модно деплоить через dockerfile.

Собственно скопировать файл на сервер можно по ssh/sftp (обычный способ), по ftp (старый способ, но уже отмирает), через админу хостинга (извращенный, но мало чего).

Чтобы заставить все работать, нужно вначале решить, как именно оно все будет работать. Можно, с nginx, можно и без. Пример [настройки](http://lesnoy.name/golang/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-nginx-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-golang-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/).

Пример конфига nginx

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name lesnoy.name; # домен

  location / {
      root      /app/;
      include       fastcgi_params;
      proxy_pass    http://localhost:9001;
  }
}
```

и в коде go нужно только слушать в нужном месте запросы

```
http.ListenAndServe(":9001", nil)
```

2. Файлы нужно просто скопировать в нужное место. Литературы на эту тему много, просто  читайте любое руководство для php/python/web программистов.
3. Порт, которым все будет наружу, определят в Вашем случае nginx (параметр `listen 80`). То, где будет слушать локально nginx и go бинарь в примере выше - порт 9001.
4. Если решили использовать sqlite базу, то для хостера это просто обычный файл. Поэтому, если база "разрастется", то скорее всего упретесь в ограничение по размеру места на диске, и возможно, в кол-во обращений к диску. Сам файл нужно просто разместить в укромном месте (чтобы не был доступен с внешнего мира, но мало чего, вдруг нужно).

> Будут ли какие то санкции применятся со стороны хоста, за то что я сожрал своей базой много ресурсов?

да просто нельзя будет записать в файл. Скорее всего будет выглядеть как будто кончилось место на диске.

5. Естественно, нужно знать хоть немного go. Желательно знать, что такое HTTP/GET/POST запросы. Немного знать HTML/javascript (теоретически бекэнд разработчик может обойтись без этого, но на практике редко бывают  чистые бекэенды.)